# Does Clojure's identical? function only return true if the things being compared are actually the same instance?

Tags: clojure

I thought

```
(identical? x y)
```

only returns true if both x and y are the same instance? So what about this:

```
(def moo 4)
(def cow 4)

(identical? moo cow)
true
```

Yet I thought both moo and cow are separate instances of the integer '4'? What gives?

Answer (score 8):

In JVM two equal integers between `-128` and `127` are always identical, because it maintains [IntegerCache](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.IntegerCache).

It means that two equal integers between -128 and 127 are always the same instance of `Integer` class.

Try comparing different integers:

```clj
(identical? 4 (+ 2 2)) ; true
(identical? 127 127) ; true
(identical? 128 128) ; false
```

See [this answer on Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28818) for more info.

Comment: thanks, why does the JVM only do this for the first byte? (ie -128 to 127)?

Comment: It is based on the assumption that small values occur much more often than other integers, so it makes sense to cache them.